# Can't create Twilio ChatClient on android

Tags: android, twilio, chat

I'm trying to build chat application on Android and I've stuck on a very first step. I can't create ChatClient. According to documentation I should call some method like this:

`ChatClient.create(context.getApplicationContext(), token, props, myCallback);`

Unfortunately I'm receiving error: "Invalid access token grants", you can check this [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/20106) for error details.

I've verified what's inside my jwt access token and it seems that everything is OK with grants. I've used https://jwt.io/ debugger to test it and could see the following payload(I've dashed my credentials to show only structure):

```
{ "iss": "SK####################",
  "exp": 1516198358,
   "jti": "SK#####################", 
   "sub": "######################", 
   "grants": { 
         "identity": "test.user@mail.com", 
         "chat": { 
             "service_sid": "###################",
             "endpoint_id": "###################"
         } 
    }
 }
```

I've checked all the values and they seem to be OK, I've also tried to copy this token and pass it to my web(JS) project and was able to sign in without any issues which proves that token itself should be OK.

Any help appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution was to use correct region setting, because tokens in one region are incompatible with services from another.

Error messages on the service side are being refined to better reflect this case.

Answer (score 1):

please do not use "endpoint_id" in the grants, it has been deprecated and may be throwing off some service validation logic.

If you continue getting this error please contact support.twilio.com and provide adb logs and the token itself (do not paste it here publicly). Also see https://github.com/twilio/twilio-chat-demo-android/blob/master/REPORT_BUGS.md

Comment: Removing this part from grants haven't solved my problem. Right now I've posted ticket to support with debug info waiting for answer.

Comment: I'm rather wondering what version of mobile SDK should I use. I see on website that current one is 2.0.4. But for that version there is an example that states to use endpoint_id in grants. So long story short - how can I find up-to-date info?

Comment: Current one is 2.0.5, and it does not need endpoint_id in the grants - this has been obsoleted for more than 6 months already.

Comment: Can you please tell me the support ticket number if you have it?

Comment: support/tickets/1224891

Comment: As it was mentioned elsewhere - make sure you are using prod tokens in prod, i.e. don't use your TEST token when using `setRegion("us1")` in ChatClient properties (or default properties).